# What are the statistical properties of average partial effect in nonlinear models?

Tags: econometrics, logit, probit, nonlinear, marginal-effect

Using a linear model like OLS, the marginal effects are simply the coefficients given by $\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$.

However, in a nonlinear model, it is more difficult to derive marginal effects.

For instance, in the logic/probit model, you typically compute the partial effect at the mean or the average partial effect. How can you evaluate these partial effects in a statistical meaningful sense? I mean, which properties will you derive in order to show that these are "true" partial effects?

I consider this because I'm trying to derive marginal effects in a highly nonlinear model, and I don't know how to be certain about the estimates.

Comment: You could also average the marginal effects rather than evaluating the derivative at the mean value of the covariates. More importantly, you can use the delta method to calculate the standard errors of these marginal effects. If the derivative is too hard, you can also just estimate, predict with x=k and at x=k+1, take the difference of the two, and bootstrap this whole process to get the SEs that way.

Comment: So if I can establish standard errors and these are sufficiently "narrow", then I should be able to conclude that the partial effect is statistical sound?

Comment: You would learn something about statistical significance by doing this. I would argue that is only one part of soundness. You might still have other worries that keep you up at night (bias, practical significance) and also about the standard errors themselves (efficiency).